# SQLite in-memory encryption

Tags: ios, sqlite, encryption

As some of you know, it is possible to create an SQLite DB in memory and save it later to disk. It is also possible to load a DB from disk into memory to work with it in memory. Now in my project, I am only allowed to save *encrypted* data to disk. The requirements are:

- I am “strictly” not allowed to first save the unencrypted data and then encrypt it.
- I have to encrypt the whole DB.
- I have to do the encryption with my own keys.
- I can’t use any third-party libraries.

EDIT:
Ist it possible to convert the Sqlite-Handle to NSData?
Does the Sqlite-Handle really contains every thing?

Comment: I hope that as well as doing proper encryption of your DB, that you are not just keeping the encryption keys hardcoded in your App where they could be extracted by a bad guy.  You need to consider security as an overall philosophy and not just for one aspect of your data.

Comment: This is off topic. Keys are downloaded online, and the whole stuff even gets salted by the encryptor.

Comment: @user1423640 Well there you go .. you have thought it through!  Given your edit all I could then suggest is reading https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/GeneralPurposeCrypto/GeneralPurposeCrypto.html  but I guess that you should have seen that by now

Comment: http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html ?
The SQLite Encryption Extension (SEE)

Comment: Costs 2000 USD! :) And appart from this I cant use my own encryption.